# Inheritance in c++ : destructors

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, destructor, virtual-destructor

I added a protected member array in the abstract base class that each derived class uses, should the destructor of the base class be virtual or can I do:

```
**~base(){
   delete[] array;
}**
```

Comment: Destructor of an abstract base class should always be virtual.

Comment: Why "or"? `delete[]` must be in the `~base()` destructor, and whether or not you want it `virtual` is not related.

Comment: Do not use explicitly `new` and `delete` in modern C++! Use `std::vector`, `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` and other similar RAII patterns.

Comment: we are not allowed to use anything from the STL

Answer (score 0):

**Both!**

You can provide a definition for the base destructor (even if it's pure virtual!) and, if the base is where the resource lives, then the base is where it should be cleaned up.

---

Alternatively, get yourself a nice `std::vector` so it's all done for you.

Comment: thank you so much for you help! what i did was that i defined a destructor in the base class with delete[] but i'm getting SIGTRAP

Comment: @AdanSuleiman That's some unrelated problem, which we can't solve without getting a [mcve] from you.

Answer (score 0):

> I added a protected member array in the **abstract base class** that each
> derived class uses, should the **destructor of the base class be virtual**

Yes.

When you use polymorphism desctructor should be also virtual.

There is official guideline for that:

[CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.md at master · isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines · GitHub](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-dtor)

> #### C.127: A class with a virtual function should have a virtual or protected destructor
>
> Reason
>
> A class with a virtual function is usually (and in general) used via a pointer to base. Usually, the last user has to call delete on a pointer to base, often via a smart pointer to base, so the destructor should be public and virtual. Less commonly, if deletion through a pointer to base is not intended to be supported, the destructor should be protected and non-virtual; see [C.35](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-dtor-virtual).
>
> Example, bad
>
> ```
> struct B {
>     virtual int f() = 0;
>     // ... no user-written destructor, defaults to public non-virtual ...
> };
>
> // bad: derived from a class without a virtual destructor
> struct D : B {
>     string s {"default"};
> };
>
> void use()
> {
>     unique_ptr<B> p = make_unique<D>();
>     // ...
> } // undefined behavior, might call B::~B only and leak the string
> ```
>
> Note
>
> There are people who don't follow this rule because they plan to use a class only through a `shared_ptr`: `std::shared_ptr<B> p = std::make_shared<D>(args);` Here, the shared pointer will take care of deletion, so no leak will occur from an inappropriate `delete` of the base. People who do this consistently can get a false positive, but the rule is important -- what if one was allocated using `make_unique`? It's not safe unless the author of `B` ensures that it can never be misused, such as by making all constructors private and providing a factory function to enforce the allocation with `make_shared`.
>
> Enforcement
>
> - A class with any virtual functions should have a destructor that is either public and virtual or else protected and non-virtual.
> - Flag `delete` of a class with a virtual function but no virtual destructor.